# How should a Stack Trace's Frame be rewritten for internal node references?

Tags: node.js, sentry

This question relates to Sentry.io in use in a NodeJS environment. The stack trace contains occasional references to internal NodeJS files with names like `node:internal/process/task_queues` and Sentry warns that source code was not found.

How can I either suppress the error, or (preferably) resolve the missing file reference so it all works smoothly? I know I can rewrite the stack trace's frame with the Rewrite integration, but I'm not sure how to handle those specific files or if that's the way to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

Sentry should not attempt to process internal frames. If that's the case, please file an issue in our main repo - https://github.com/getsentry/sentry